# Retrieve JSON object Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I am able to get this JSON using Swift:

```
{
  "estado": "1",
  "turno": {
    "_id": "1",
    "_idEmpresa": "1",
    "_idCentro": "1",
    "Descripcion": "LOCAL",
    "TurnoActual": "40",
    "TurnoSiguiente": "53",
    "Version": "2185"
  }
}
```

using the following code:

```
let estado =  json["estado"] as? String
if estado == "1" {
   print("Estado OK")
}
```

However, I want to access the turn attributes. I have tried many combinations without success.

If it's possible, I want to have something as I do on Android to get turno directly as an object Turno.

Could you guys help me with this?

Comment: Do you use SwiftyJson plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
let dictResult = json["turno"] as! NSDictionary
let id = dictResult["_id"] as! String
let idEmpresa = dictResult["_idEmpresa"] as! String

// OR you can directly get data, if you have json as a NSDictionary

let id = json.objectForKey("turno")?.objectForKey("_id") as! String
let idEmpresa = json.objectForKey("turno")?.objectForKey("_idEmpresa") as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

`turno` is a dictionary with `String` keys and `String` values, therefore a  downcast is not needed.

This example prints the value for keys `_id` and `Descripcion` if available.

```
if let turno = json["turno"] as? [String:String] {
   if let identifier = turno["_id"] { print(identifier) }
   if let description = turno["Descripcion"] { print(description) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any Swift library that could automatically create an object from your dictionary.

But it's not hard to make it yourself, there's just some boilerplate.

An example could be like this...

Make your object and its initializer based on your dictionary keys:

```
struct Turno {

    let _id:String
    let _idEmpresa:String
    let _idCentro:String
    let description:String
    let turnoActual:String
    let turnoSiguiente:String
    let version:String

    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:String]) {
        _id = dictionary["_id"] ?? ""
        _idEmpresa = dictionary["_idEmpresa"] ?? ""
        _idCentro = dictionary["_idCentro"] ?? ""
        description = dictionary["Descripcion"] ?? ""
        turnoActual = dictionary["TurnoActual"] ?? ""
        turnoSiguiente = dictionary["TurnoSiguiente"] ?? ""
        version = dictionary["Version"] ?? ""
    }
}
```

Then pass the dictionary to the struct constructor:

```
if let content = json["turno"] as? [String:String] {

    let turno = Turno(fromDictionary: content)

    print(turno._id)
    print(turno._idEmpresa)
    print(turno._idCentro)
    print(turno.description)
    print(turno.turnoActual)
    print(turno.turnoSiguiente)
    print(turno.version)

}
```